# Disabling the keyboard in windows c++?

Tags: c++, windows, keyboard

How can I completely disable the keyboard using c++ in windows? And by completely disable I mean so even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> doesn't work. I did consider using a keyboard driver but I think you need to restart the computer after it is installed, but since I only need to disable it for a couple minutes that wouldn't really work.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?

Answer (score 13):

This is not really possible.

WinLogon is designed as the one process that intercepts the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> key press, even when all other things hang or die.
This is the failsafe against malicious sessions, etc. So there is no obvious workaround.

Maybe a keyboard filter driver would make your request possible, but that is a real kernel-driver.

Answer (score 9):

You can't disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd> without removing the keyboard or replacing the keyboard driver, it generates a kernel level notification.

Answer (score 1):

You could install a keyboard hook and filter out the messages, but you might need to have your application as the top most window. Even then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> would not get filtered out.

Here's [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx) on MSDN

Example of [Hooking the Keyboard](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/keyboard/article.php/c5699)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [BlockInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646290%28VS.85%29.aspx) function. But it doesn't block <kbd>CTRL + ALT + DEL</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here goes several random suggestions.  I don't have a definitite answer, but here's where I would start:

1) SetupDiRemoveDevice is probably the API you want to call.  Although to call it, you'll need to make a lot of other device enumeration calls.  Enumerate your HID and USB devices and find the keyboard.  Start by looking for the VID/PID of the actual device for starters.

2) Delete the drivers kdbclass.sys and kbdhid.sys.  You'll be fighting Windows system file to do this.  I have no idea if this will work, but sounds interesting and simple.

3) Write a USB filter driver.  Your driver will need to know (or be passed) the vid/pid of the device to filter on, but it might work.