# windows: load a filter driver while windows is running

Tags: c++, keyboard, filter, installation, driver

Is it possible to install a keyboard filter driver(like ctrl2cap) while windows is running and not having to reboot? I tried it once with a driver loader but I got a BSOD. If it is possible what was I doing wrong? What can I do next time to not get a BSOD? Also, if it is possible, could I do it with c++? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214648/disabling-the-keyboard-in-windows-c posted by same user a few minurtes ago. To the user - make them part of the same question - I'm voting to close this one.

Comment: @Paul Nathan: I disagree. The inf file and kernel/DDK API routines needed definitely fall into the realm of programming. If it was a permissions issue, then I would agree that superuser is the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is you cannot dynamically load a filter driver. You need to specify a load order when you install the filter driver. I assume the filter driver is layered on top of kbdclass. As kbdclass is already loaded this is not possible.

Comment: Hi Steve,how can I get that the filter driver is layered on top of the KBDCLASS? can you tell me how it is possible? o where can I start to learn about this matter?